# How can I export my RDS data from one aws account of aurora DB [aws] to another aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

How can I export data from an Aurora RDS database and import it into another AWS account?

The Aurora DB has additional proxy tied to it, therefore copying the Aurora as a whole does not function. Is there another option for me to complete this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can share a snapshot https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-share-snapshot.html

Answer (score 1):

Another option for copying across accounts (but only within the same AWS Region) is cross-account cloning:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/Aurora.Managing.Clone.html#Aurora.Managing.Clone.Cross-Account